# Are Saturated Ideals Radical?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am reading the section 5.5 of Gathmann's [note](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/alggeom-2002/alggeom-2002.pdf). In the note, saturated ideal is defined as follows:

For a homogeneous ideal $I \subseteq S = k[x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n]$, the *saturation ideal* of $I$ is defined by

$\overline{I} = \{\, s \in S : \forall i \, \exists m > 0, \ x_i^ms \in I \,\}.$

In the Gathmann's note Lemma 5.5.9, it is stated that for homogeneous ideals $I, J \subseteq S$

1. $\overline{I}$ is homogeneous
2. $V_+(I) = V_+(\overline{I})$
3. $V_+(\overline{I}) = V_+(\overline{J}) \Leftrightarrow \overline{I} = \overline{J}$

From these I concluded that for any homogeneous ideal $I \subseteq S_+$

$V_+(\overline{ \sqrt{I} }) = V_+(\sqrt{I}) = V_+(I) = V_+(\overline{I})$, hence $\overline{\sqrt{I}} = \overline{I}.$

And there for letting $J = \overline{I}$ we have

$J = \overline{J} = \overline{\sqrt{J}} \supseteq \sqrt{J} \supseteq J$ and $J = \sqrt{J}.$

However, I have a counterexample where $S = k[x_0, x_1]$ and

$I = (x_0^2), \ \sqrt{I} = (x_0), \ J = \overline{I} = (x_0^2), \ \sqrt{J} = (x_0)$

so $J \neq \sqrt{J}.$

Where did I go wrong in these arguments?

Comment: The 3rd point you mention in Lemma 5.5.9 is clearly not true.

Comment: Unless you mean $V_+(I)=V_+(J)$ as subschemes not merely as topological subspaces, in that case $V_+(\sqrt{I})=V_+(I)$ becomes wrong as they're the same subspace, but with different scheme structure.

Comment: @A.Rod Proj S/I = Proj S/J means that they are set-theoretically the same regarded as subset of Proj S, AND they are isomorphic as schemes through a morphism over k?

Comment: It should means they're equal as schemes, which is a bit of a weird thing, but in particular it implies that they should be isomorphic as schemes, and that wont be the case for $Proj(S/x_0)$ and $Proj(S/x_0^2)$

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, different homogeneous ideals can give rise to the same closed *subscheme*, and for a homogeneous ideal $I$, the largest ideal yielding the same closed subscheme as $I$ is its saturation $\bar I$. So Lemma 5.5.9 (3) is really about subschemes.

Thus there is a bijection between saturated homogeneous ideals in $S$ and closed subschemes of $\mathbb P^n$.

On the other hand, different closed subschemes can have the same closed subset, and the radical of $I$ is the largest homogeneous ideal yielding the same closed subset as $I$.

Thus there is a bijection between the homogeneous radical ideals of $S$ and the closed subsets of $\mathbb P^n$.

This agrees with the easy implication that radical implies saturated for homogeneous ideals.

Note this plays a role in the Hilbert scheme, which parameterises closed subschemes of projective space (having the same Hilbert polynomial). One way of constructing this is by parameterising the corresponding homogeneous saturated ideals, which can be done using Grassmannians on the subspace of monomials of some suitable degree.